# ASP.NET Using JQuery with nested, editable GridViews with expand/colapse features

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

One part of my application uses nested `GridViews` in order to display data. I have clients' orders, and each order consists of 1-or-more products. Now, in order to present data to the user, I used the order data `GridView` with a button in each row, which allows you to expand/collapse the child `Gridview`.

When designing this I followed the tutorial presented on this page:

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Nested-GridViews-GridView-inside-GridView-with-Expand-and-Collapse-feature.aspx

with some modifications, since my situation is a little bit different (E.g. I don't use a database since data is imported from the external API).

However, the problem is that in the original code the child `GridView` data is only displayed, while in my solution it has some `DropDownLists` that allows user to edit the data:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MainTable" runat="server" OnDataBound="MainTable_DataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="MainTable_RowCommand" class="w3-table w3-centered">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="w3-blue" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a class="w3-btn w3-blue button" id="plus">+</a>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                        <asp:GridView ID="ProductsTable" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="ProductsTable_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="w3-table w3-striped">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Nazwa" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Indexer" Visible="false" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parametr 1">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" class="w3-select w3-border"></asp:DropDownList>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parametr 2">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" class="w3-select w3-border"></asp:DropDownList>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parametr 3">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" class="w3-select w3-border"></asp:DropDownList>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Usuń">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <a class="w3-btn w3-blue verify">V</a>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Client" HeaderText="Klient" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Telefon" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Comment" HeaderText="Komentarz" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Zatwierdź">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button class="w3-btn w3-blue" Text="Zatwierdź" runat="server" CommandName="Verify" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Now, the JQuery used in the original code creates a copy of child `GridView`, which is removed when the user clicks the "-" button. Because of that, I can't access `DropDownLists` in the code and the changes made by user are not saved. I also found out that the buttons in the child `GridView` (class `.verify`) aren't working properly (This, however, might be my fault since I'm not really fluent in JQuery).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".button").on("click", function () {
                if ($(this).attr('id') == "plus") {
                    $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
                    $(this).html("-");
                    $(this).attr('id', 'minus');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).html("+");
                    $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
                    $(this).attr('id', 'plus');
                }
            });
            $(".verify").on("click", function () {
                $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
            });
        });
```

So my question is - how to maintain the current look and page design of the application (opening child GridView outside of the cell), while still being able to access `DropDownLists` in the code behind? is it possible to do it with JQuery? If not, do you have any other ideas on how to resolve this?

[**EDIT**] Here are some pics of how it looks:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use hide() instead of remove(). Like so:

```
 $(this).html("+");
 $(this).closest("tr").next().hide();
 $(this).attr('id', 'plus');
```

Comment: In this case, using the hide() method will result in adding new table rows every time the user clicks the "+" button. If I solve the main problem - which is creating a new object each time, instead of using the existing one, while still maintaining the current design -  the hide() method will be much more useful